# Prevent the console from overwrting a line

Tags: c#

Is there a way for me to stop the console from printing to the top line?
So :

> this line in the console doesn't change
>
> but this one and the ones under it can

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you want leave the first line alone without overwrite it, you can use `Console.SetCursorPosition`.

Example

```
// Set cursor starting from the second line
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
Console.WriteLine("The second line");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could mame your own printline function that always prints the line you want to keep+the changed line, which you pass to it as a parameter. Or you could make your own one line console.

```
void print(string toPrint){
  clearConsole();
  Console.write("string to keep");
  Console.write(toPrint);
}

void clearConsole(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    Console.write(" ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see. Would this also keep the line if the console fills and is forced to move up a line?

Comment: Edited. Need 15 characters to post comment.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this code :

```
Console.WriteLine("x\nx");
```

it should print :

```
x 

x
```

But if your question was that you simply wanted to skip a line for better visibility:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

it will skip a line. If you wanted to put something on that line you could also do that by typing that inside the parameter.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is after